# Template literals where nothing gets rendered if the condition is not satisfied

Tags: javascript, jsx, template-literals

I am wondering what is an elegant way of making a conditional where nothing gets rendered if the condition is not satisfied?

I have tried with this:

```
{`${dateFormat(fom)} - ${dateValid && dateFormat(tom)}`}
```

But, then `false` gets rendered and if I do this:

```
{`${dateFormat(fom)} - ${dateValid ? dateFormat(tom) : null}`}
```

Then `null` gets rendered.
Is there a way of doing this without ternary operator and using empty string like this:

```
{`${dateFormat(fom)} - ${dateValid ? dateFormat(tom) : ''}`}
```

How can I achieve this in a template literal with something that looks more elegant than the above code?

Comment: You could do the calculation in advance so it does not appear in the template. But you'll still have the logic ( ternary or not ) somewhere. `const date_template =  dateFormat(fom) - dateValid ? dateFormat(fom) : '';` and `${ date_template }` I just use the ternaries inside the template tbh: `${ dateFormat(fom) - dateValid ? dateFormat(fom) : '' }`, so your 3rd option I guess.